# Azure IOT Hub to JavaScript Code?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have a device connected to Azure IOT Hub. I have messages coming to the hub for every 20 Sec. Now for every incoming message I have some business logic to execute. I have attached event hub and stream analytics to the IOT Hub to fetch the latest record but again I am only capable of pushing it to BLOB Storage. How can I get the latest message/events as a json out of the system.

I found out that Azure Functions is a go. But I am finding samples from C#, I am looking for JavaScript/Java.

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an Azure Function to your Event Hub with event hub trigger. You can find examples of such function in

- [Azure Event Hubs bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---javascript-example)
- [Processing data from IoT Hub with Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/)

Comment: Perfect, This is what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: The links you shared are in deed a very good resource, I just don't know how to do the step 2.4 of the first link through the command line - the event hub connection. Once it's created I can use the name in a function in the `function.json` file.

Comment: I found how to set the `connection` manually. See: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50024#issuecomment-723067983